# SQLRPGLE: RNQ0105: A character representation of a numeric value is in error (C G D F)

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am in a sqlrpgle program, and getting this error on runtime:

"statement 005500 performed a conversion from character to numeric using data 
that was in error."

```
55: ModChar =      %CHAR(ControlTable.CCSDSC);       
56: ResultChar =   %CHAR(ControlTable.CCNOT1);       
57: SRunChar =     %CHAR(ControlTable.CCNOT2);       

59: ZccMod =       %DEC(%SUBST(ModChar:1:2):2:0);    
60: ZccResult =    %DEC(%SUBST(ResultChar:1:2):2:0); 
61: ZccSingleRun = %DEC(%SUBST(SRunChar:1:2):2:0);
```

The ControlTable.CCSDSC is of type Graphic, and I am using %CHAR to convert it to character, then getting the first 2 characters of that (substring) and converting it into a packed decimal format. what am I doing wrong here? **Or is it that the parameter that I am putting in that has an error?**

Comment: Look at the raw data in debug, and maybe that will give you a hint as to what is happening. `%Dec` only supports digits (0-1), decimal seperator (either a period or comma), space x'40', and a sign (+ or -).

Comment: I am using %dec on "00" which is what Control.CCSDSC is, so shouldn't it work?

Comment: It should, that is why I wanted you to look at the raw hex data in debug, it should look like x'F0F0'

Comment: I don't have enough authority to do the debug. I figured out the problem, which was that I was using ControlTable.**** BEFORE creating the ControlTable...Dumb error on my part...-__- Thank you for the help